# How can I Update-Database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, migration, package-manager-console

this is the code used to generate the migration

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context DataContext --output-dir Migrations/SqlServerMigrations`
and this is the DataContext.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to sql server database
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase"));
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

but when I run
`Upadate-Database` 
I get the error
"More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context' parameter for dotnet commands."

How can I update the database using this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update-Database --context DataContext
```

As a part of the `ef migrations add`, you specify your context as `DataContext`. I believe the above command should allow you to update the database accordingly.

Comment: I get this error now "Update-Database : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'DataContext'."

Comment: Fixed it just had to use -context not --context, thank you very much